# Request.RawUrl will get everything after the root url, what will give me just the filename?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a built in way of just getting the filename for the current request?

Request.RawUrl will give everything AFTER the domain (including querystring), is there anything to just give me the current filename being requested?

Answer (score 1):

A more simple approach could be:

```
string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.LocalPath);
```

Comment: This approach will break if you use it with web service requests (e.g. where the Request.Url.LocalPath is something like "/Services/SomeService.asmx/SomeFunction").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the best approach, but something like

```
System.IO.Path.GetFilename(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath)
```

will take into account any `Server.Transfer()`ing that might have occurred, and will play nice with web service requests.